# How to pass item as parameter with TouchableWithoutFeedback

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
trigger = () => {
  console.log('testing');
}

render() {
  return (    
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.videos}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress={this.trigger}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.videoId.toString()}
    />
  )
}
```

The above code works fine, to have a list of items being rendered and `onLongPress` will execute the function and do the `console.log`, but, it couldnt know which item was being long pressed.

Now in order to know which item being `longPress`, I try setting `trigger` to accept one parameter and passing the `item` along the function call.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress={this.trigger(item)}>
  <Text>{item.title}</Text>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>

trigger = item => {
  console.log('testing', item);
}
```

What I noticed is, once the list being loaded, the function `trigger` being triggered automatically for each and every item. and `onLongPress` does not responding at all. I figured it's something to do with binding. I've tried the below way too but failed

```
onLongPress={this.trigger.bind(item)}
onLongPress={this.trigger.bind(this)}
onLongPress={() => this.trigger.bind(this)}
onLongPress={item => this.trigger.bind(item)}
```

Neither of the ways above works. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `trigger` function at the `onLongPress` event, as per your shared code you are calling the function during render time.

Try this

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress={() => this.trigger(item)}>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: omg this got me crazy..way too many patterns and honestly haven't really understand when to use which. Do you happen to have any good reading materials

Comment: Any idea that why `item => this.trigger(item)` is not working?

Comment: Yeah, the reason is that `item` became local to the event handler and it's shadowing the global one. Also `onLongPress` doesn't pass any arguments to the event handler. So the approach was wrong.

Comment: Read https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reactjs-pass-parameters-to-event-handlers-ca1f5c422b9 blog, its look good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onLongPress={item => this.toggleModal.bind(this, item)}
```

or even this works

```
//In the constructor, setup the binding
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.toggleModal= this.toggleModal.bind(this)
}

//To call this function
onLongPress=item => this.toggleModal(item)
```

or this ES6 way also works, simple and short

```
onLongPress={item => this.toggleModal(item)}
```

Comment: Nope, not responding, no error but no `console.log` either